# django - is the default auth.user enough?

Tags: python, django, database, authentication

I am working in django, I am planning a database for rides for users.

- each User can be on multiple Rides (over time) and each Ride can have multiple Users (passengers) in it.
- The front-end will be an android application.

a User will have to log-in to the app (via phone number authentication for example) and then - will be able either to tag along to a existing ride or add a new ride (meaning the user is the driver) and have other users tag along to it.

**My question is** - Does the default auth.user enough for this stuff? how can I extend and add members to the class? do I even need to?

Comment: It's all documented here on the django site.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Answer (score 0):

Yes, auth.user is more than enough for your needs.

The Django documentation has good information on storing additional information about users: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users